# как добавить кнопку в админку django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-admin

Мне нужно добавить кнопку, которая ведет на другую страницу, в админке django. Подскажите как это можно сделать.

Comment: Зависит от того, куда именно нужно добавить кнопку

Comment: На главную страницу админки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

найди файл index.html, который находится в
`django\contrib\admin\templates\admin\index.html`
это базовый файл для главной страницы админки.
У себя в папке `templates` создай папку `admin`, скопируй в нее этот файл и в нем вноси изменения которые тебе нужны